# Создал инсталятор для проекта visual studio, после устновки приложение не запускается

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал инсталятор для visual studio через project setup, после установки пишет что базу не может читать. Базу создавал на sqlite. можете обьяснить в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, проблема в UAС. Для того, чтобы взаимодействовать с файлами из ProgramFiles, вам нужны административные привилегии.
Обходится это, обычно, помещением "изменяемой" части программы - БД, настройки и прочие в папку приложения, расположенную в %ProgramData%. Там вы можете спокойно работать со своей БД без запроса привилегий администратора.

Да, это справедливо только для систем, где есть UAC, т.е. для Windows XP такое решение не подойдет и причины там нужно выяснять отдельно, логированием и прочими делами.